# Parameterizing a SQL IN clause on an integer column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, in-clause

Jeff Atwood asked the original question about [parameterizing a SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause), but I want to do this with an integer column.  If I try the code from the original post I get the following exception, which makes sense:

> Conversion failed when converting the
>   varchar value '%|' to data type int.

Anyone try this before?

Comment: The top voted answer (not the accepted one) in the linked question has the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337792#337792

Comment: And then there is the MSSQL2008 specific solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337864#337864

Comment: As @Jørn notes, you should use Mark Brackett's solution instead. If you must use Spolsky's, then you'll need to convert the numbers to character data instead. If you look at my comments on the accepted answer there, you'll know why I'm not including a sample of how to fix it for your situation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Jørn Schou-Rode gave the best answer in the comments where he links to the top answer from this question:

[Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337792#337792)